# combine array php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

In my output code is as:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 53,67,70
    [1] => 48 
    [2] => 11,22,13 
);
```

I want in output as: **array(11,22,13,48,53,67,70)**

```
    $result = $this->db->get_where('table',array('mainpage'=>$mp'));
    $data = array();
    $out = array();
    foreach($result->result() as $row){
        $dv = json_decode($row->subpage);
        $out = array_merge($dv, $out);
    }
    return    $out;
```

In my database table rows are as: (json data)

**Row 1 :** ["11,22,13"]
**Row 2 :** ["48"]
**Row 3 :** ["53,67,70"]

How must fixed php code for output as `array(11,22,13,48,53,67,70)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $this->db->get_where('table',array('mainpage'=>$mp));
$data = array();
$out = array();

foreach($result->result() as $row){
        $dv = json_decode($row->subpage);

        $flat = array();

        foreach ( $dv as $item ) {
            $flat = array_merge( $flat, explode( ',', $item ) );
        }

        $out = array_merge( $out, $flat );
}

return $out;
```

Comment: Sorry, a comma was missing. Fixed

Comment: ok but still i have error, see: http://pastebin.com/i9k9HJkE Line 132 is thie: `$out = array_merge($out, explode( ',', $dv));` ?

Comment: Right I see.. please see if the updated answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array (array (53, 67, 70), array (48), array (11, 22, 13));
$combined_array = call_user_func_array ('array_merge', $array);
```