# Checks if several values exists in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want check if exists several values (EX: `5`,`110`) in array return is true. (without use loop)

I don't use from loop because i want load a page if return was true

**AS:**

```
if(in_array('5' OR '110', array('5,4,2,66,12,110'))){
    echo 'true';//Load page
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

How is it?

Answer (score 6):

```
if(array_intersect(array('15', '110'), explode(',', '5,4,2,66,12,110'))){
    echo 'true';//Load a page
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: @TaylorGomez This works: http://codepad.org/e4uUgGw8 Use `var_export` instead of `var_dump` if you want to get the string representation of an array.

Comment: I getting output array of this php code: http://codepad.org/OucFsUHH and To explain it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920117/combine-array-php/ ????

Comment: @TaylorGomez put your code in the object method that has $this and a reference to the db oject.

Comment: @TaylorGomez where did you get your code from another question?

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=array(5,4,2,66,12,110);
if(in_array('5',$a) OR in_array('10',$a )){
    echo 'true';//Load page
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a fast method use this:

```
if ( preg_match ( '/(^|,)(5|110)(,|$)/','5,4,2,66,12,110' ) )
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

**EDIT**

```
if ( preg_match ( "/(^|,)(" . implode ('|', $needles ) . ")(,|$)/", implode (',', $haystack ) ) )
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

Comment: you can use implode to merge array into string with commas.

Comment: sure, but that's not in your 'answer'